Make Sheets recognize date from text
There's column A that I'd like to convert to a datetime object. I tried with custom formatting but I got no results. I also tried to change the locale to the one I'm currently located and then the custom format but still didn't get anywhere.
The final results I'd like is a column with YYYY-MM-DD.
Example sheet

Try this formula in row 2 of an empty column :
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10,"at",),"YYYY-MM-DD"))


That works to at least get the value I want, but it seems that still Google Sheets doesn't recognize it as a date, is there a way to achieve that?

after you remove the "at" it does recognize it as a date.

=ISDATE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"at",)) returns TRUE.

Thank you! Normally on date fields I get a calendar view when I double click and I'm not getting it in this case. Anyways, do you have an explanation on why the custom date format wasn't working?

you can select the range, Ctrl + H find "at" and replace it with nothing. It will convert the values to dates and give you the dropdown.


You may try:
=arrayformula(query(--left(A2:A,find("at",A2:A)-2),"format Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd'",0))

